# DataFrameセル内のリストを列方向に展開したい

Tags: python, python3, pandas

今、以下のような各セルにリストが入ったDataFrameがあります。

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': [['Li', 'C'], ['Li', 'N'], ['Li', 'O']]},
    index=[1, 2, 3])
```

このDataFrameを以下のように加工をしたいです。

```
x1,  x2                    
'Li', 'C'
'Li', 'N'
'Li', 'O'
```

```
df_split = df.apply(pd.Series)
df_split = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['elements']).unstack().reset_index(1), axis=1)
```

を試してみたのですが、うまく動きませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

```py
dfx = df['x'].apply(pd.Series).set_axis(['x1', 'x2'], axis=1)
print(dfx)

#
   x1 x2
1  Li  C
2  Li  N
3  Li  O
```